# linux cpu temperature

Tags: linux, cpu, temperature

How can I find out the cpu temperature of my linux desktop?
What does

```
acpi -t
```

measure? The man page doesn't really say more than 'thermal information'. Judging from ACPI = advanced config and power interface, and the fact that all googles for info about that command brings up forum posts about laptops, I would guess it's battery temp?
Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors` (once), then [`sensors`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sensors) (every time you want to check) in a terminal window.

Comment: thanks for the answer - this works perfectly! Also, searching for lm-sensors in synaptic led me to discover 'psensor' which is a graphical monitor that also shows gpu temp..

Comment: There's **hddtemp** as well, and I've used Gnome panel applets like 
**sensors-applet** and **computertemp** in the past.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Install the *lm-sensors* packet: `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`

**2)** Start the sensors detection: `sudo sensors-detect`

**3)** In a terminal run `sensors` to read the sensors data...

*Details*: lm-sensors packet install these files:

System executables in /sbin (system binaries):

/usr/sbin/fancontrol
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig
/usr/sbin/sensors-detect

The *sensors* utility in

/usr/bin/sensors

The shell scripts in /etc/init.d

/etc/init.d/lm-sensors allow to start, stop or restart the daemon /usr/bin/sensors

Comment: after sensors-detect, i had to do `sudo service module-init-tools start`